# Asynchronicity between behavior and flows on Mitmproxy

Tags: mitmproxy

I am trying to reverse engineer the API of an IoT device using mitmproxy. My setup is an iphone, computer running on MacOS 10.14, and an IoT device (watering pump) that can only access the wireless network after being plugged into the computer via USB connection, i.e. a not genuinely WiFi device. My phone is configured to point to the computer, which is running mitmproxy on a standard configuration.

When I send instructions from the app controlling the device on my phone to the device itself, presumably these instructions are sent to the computer, to the device cloud server, and then to the device. With these assumptions, one would think that they would see the flow of POST requests in mitmproxy before observing the results of those instructions. That is, if you send an instruction to turn on the pump, you'd think you'd see POST request containing that instruction show up in the mitmproxy flows before you see the pump turn on.

However that is not the case here. What happens is that, when I send instructions from the app, I observe the expected behavior from the IoT device, and then the flow of requests appear on the mitmproxy console seemingly at random. There seems to be no determinate relationship between the instructions I send and the requests that appear; they show up 5 seconds later, 5 minutes later, or 30 minutes later. Is this an intentional security feature? To somehow jam MITMproxies so that hackers cannot easily isolate the knowledge of which packet is performing which instruction? Or is it just something that I am doing wrong? Does anyone have any ideas as to what could be happening hear and potential solutions for making the flow of requests appear in real time? Ty

Comment: Are you sure the communication from app to pump runs through the cloud and specifically via HTTP(S)? May be the app simply sends the data directly to the pump. I would recommend to use separate networks for app and pump to prevent direct communication.

Comment: What @Robert said - if the requests were going through mitmproxy, you should definitely see them right away.